# NextImage erroring in ie11

Tags: typescript, next.js, internet-explorer-11

i use typescript, this is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
"@webcomponents/shadydom": "^1.7.4",
"cookie": "^0.4.1",
"js-cookie": "3.0.0-rc.4",
"next": "11.1.2",
"next-seo": "^4.7.1",
"next-themes": "^0.0.14",
"postcss-custom-properties": "^12.0.0",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
"postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
"postcss-nesting": "^8.0.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-markdown": "^6.0.2" }
```

next/image can work in chrome、firefox，but not show in ie11 , render result in ie11：

```html
<div style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: relative;
 max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
       <div style="display: block; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <img aria-hidden="true" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: currentColor; border-image: none; display: block; max-width: 100%;" alt="" 
src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQwIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIvPg==">
      </div>
      <img style="margin: auto; padding: 0px; border: currentColor; border-image: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; display: block; position: absolute; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" alt="" 
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-nimg="intrinsic" decoding="async">
      <noscript>&lt;img alt="" srcSet="http://89.99.249.122:37/uploads/realtec_type_white_7e5b583ded.png 1x, http://89.99.249.122:37/uploads/realtec_type_white_7e5b583ded.png 2x" src="http://89.99.249.122:37/uploads/realtec_type_white_7e5b583ded.png" decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%" loading="lazy"/&gt;</noscript>
</div>
```

my code:

```js
import { getMyMedia } from "@utils/medias"
import NextImage from "next/image"


const Image = ({img,...props})=>{
  const media = img

  const loader = ({ src }) => {
    return getMyMedia(src)
  }

    // The image has a fixed width and height
    if (props.width && props.height) {
      return (
        <NextImage loader={loader} src={media.url} alt={media.alternativeText || ""} {...props}  />
      )
    }

      // The image is responsive
  return (
    <NextImage
      loader={loader}
      layout="responsive"
      width={media.width}
      height={media.height}
      objectFit="contain"
      src={media.url}
      alt={media.alternativeText || ""}
    />
  )

}

export default Image
```

i found error in ie11 devTools，like this：

SCRIPT5022: Should not already be working.

what should ido

Comment: When asking questions about code in libraries, in addition to sharing your code, it is also important to also share information about the versions of libraries you are using... especially when working with old browsers like IE11.

Comment: Which line of code does the error point to? Which version of next/image are you using? What is `@utils/medias`? I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. Please provide [a reproducible code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example you can use some online code editor like https://stackblitz.com/. Besides, there's [an official example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/image-component) of next/image and you can refer to it. It works well in IE 11.

Comment: sorry，i have updated the version info , "@utils/medias"  used for get  remote img data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the library `next-images`. It has support for all formats.
All you need to is specify its usage in your `next.config.js` file.

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

[Package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images)

Comment: it work！！! Do you know the reason？why ?

Comment: Sometimes Next JS builds mess up the native Image handling offering that they offer. However, this library, is a reliable option for rendering images

Comment: @YuZhou  Although the image has been showed，the rendered results are different between them, i have not figured out the meaning of these differences,so i want to observe it  first, but i still mark it,after all ,it is useful